# this.welcome() is not a function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to create a small javascript plugin like this:

```
function TextShadow(host){
    this.host_id=host;
    this.welcome=function(){alert('welcome to earth')};
    $(function(){
      this.welcome();
      $(this.host_id).html("<p>hello world</p>");
    });
 }
```

I then call it from an other script like this:

```
var test=new TextShadow("#sample");
```

but i get this.welcome is not a function.However if i change the previous code to the following one everything works fine:

```
   function TextShadow(host){
        this.host_id=host;
        this.welcome=function(){alert('welcome to earth')};
        var gen=this;
        $(function(){
          gen.welcome();
          $(gen.host_id).html("<p>hello world</p>");
        });
   }
```

Can someone explain me why the first piece of code doesn't work while the second does?

Comment: Every function has a `this` and it will depend on **how** you call the function. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: `this` is no longer referring to the `TextShadow` instance inside the DOM ready function: it is being used as a reference to the window object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the scope changes within JavaScript functions. You can `bind` the function to set `this` to the desired value.

```
function TextShadow(host){
    this.host_id=host;
    this.welcome=function(){alert('welcome to earth')};
    $(function(){
      this.welcome();
      $(this.host_id).html("<p>hello world</p>");
    }.bind(this));
 }
```

It is even cleaner in ES6 where you can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
$(() => {
  this.welcome();
  $(this.host_id).html("<p>hello world</p>");
});
```

[MDN Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)

Answer (score 1):

Because your `this` changes once you go into the anonymous function. By assigning `this` to something else: `gen`, you can still use it in a different function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind` to set `this`

```
function TextShadow(host){
this.host_id=host;
this.welcome=function(){alert('welcome to earth')};
$(function(){
  this.welcome();
  $(this.host_id).html("<p>hello world</p>");
}.bind(this));
}
```

**OR**

Use `self`or any variable to store `this` and use `self` in place of `this`

```
function TextShadow(host){
var self=this;
self.host_id=host;
self.welcome=function(){alert('welcome to earth')};
$(function(){
  self.welcome();
  $(self.host_id).html("<p>hello world</p>");
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first Function  Welcome Function Can't be seeing because **this**  Binding of the current execution context .anonymous Function is the current  execution context and you try tho access function form anther context